# "One of this and that" or "One of this or that"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I am wondering which is the proper way to say that one thing or the other is required.

> Only one of passport and national id is required.

or

> Only one of passport or national id is required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Only one of*** is effectively saying ***Only one of the following list***. It is followed by a **list** of two or more items, and therefore requires ***and***.

In your second version, with ***or***, the ***one of*** is superfluous, because the ***or*** implies a **choice** of *only one item*, as in "*Choose A **or** B **or** C ...*" (or more usually "*Choose A, B or C*").

So:

> **Only one of (the following): passport, national ID, *and* XYZ.** or
>   **Only *a* passport *or a* national ID.**

Either form can be used with two or more choices, but if there are only two choices then the ***or*** form (*without* **one of**) is briefer and clearer (in my humble opinion).

If the statement were that you need ***two*** of X, Y and Z, then using ***or*** would be wrong, because (1) ***or*** implies a single choice, and (2) with picking two or more you are choosing from a *list*, and a list requires ***and*** (not ***or***).

Answer (score 1):

How about

> *Either* a passport *or* a national id is required.

The either/or construction lets the reader know that only one of the two is required.